# Converting .vhd file to .raw - File is too small and does not boot

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, proxmox, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-v `.vhd` file I am trying to convert to `.raw` for Proxmox. However every time I convert the size is less than half of the actual disk space used and when I import it doesn't boot.

I download the `.vhd` directly off my Windows machine and run the following command to convert:

```
qemu-img convert -f vpc -O raw Rami.vhd Rami.raw
```

Then import

```
dd if=Rami.raw of=/dev/bigdata/vm-102-disk-1
```

I also tried with qcow2 but it doesn't work also (file size too small and doesn't boot). Does the disk size matter? This is a 300GB `.vhd` file and I have done the exact same thing with other `.vhd` files less than `50GB` with no problems.

What am I missing?